# Does every scheme admit an affine open subset whose sections are the ring global sections?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

The title basically says it all. Given an arbitrary scheme $X$ with global sections $\mathcal{O}_X(X)$, is there an affine open subset $U$ of $X$ such that $\mathcal{O}_X(U) = \mathcal{O}_X(X)$?

Obviously the scheme $Y=\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ has the same global sections as $X$, but it's not clear to me that you can embed $Y$ in $X$. I have been unable to produce a counter example though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $X = \Bbb{P}^1_k,$ where $k$ is your favorite field. We have $\mathcal{O}_X(X) = k,$ and note that $X$ is integral, so that the restriction maps $\mathcal{O}_X(U)\to\mathcal{O}_X(V)$ are [injective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2742112/restriction-maps-in-an-integral-scheme-are-injective-ayman-houriehs-proof). Now, notice that any proper open subscheme is contained in one of the two copies of $\Bbb{A}^1_k$ inside $\Bbb{P}^1_k.$ This means that if $U$ is any affine open subscheme of $X,$ we have injections $k\to k[x]\to\mathcal{O}_X(U).$ In particular, this shows that the map $\mathcal{O}_X(X)\to\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is never an isomorphism for an affine open subscheme $U\subseteq X.$

Comment: Of course! Somehow I managed to convince myself projective space wouldn't work. Thanks for knocking some sense into me. +1

Comment: @Nico The intuitive reason for this should probably be emphasized: there's usually going to be fewer globally regular functions than locally regular ones. For rational functions viewed naively as ratios of polynomials, you've got to avoid singularities. If you're insisting they're regular on all of $\mathbb{P}_k^1$, the only way to get them to behave well at infinity is if they're constant. Omitting the point at infinity gives you all the polynomials. Omitting some more points still gives you those polynomials, as well more rational functions.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson Thank you for the intuition, that helps a lot. Indeed, it seems the properness of $\mathbb P^1$ is what makes this example tick. I thought about some non-proper examples like a line with two origins but clearly that doesn't serve as a counter-example. Perhaps my claim is true for non-proper schemes but somehow I highly doubt it.

Comment: @Nico The same idea will work for $X = \Bbb{A}^1$! Let's take $k$ algebraically closed for good luck. Any proper affine open subscheme $U\subseteq X$ will avoid some closed point $p\in\Bbb{A}^1$ corresponding to $(x - \alpha)$ for some $\alpha\in k$. Then $\Bbb{A}^1\setminus\{p\}\cong\operatorname{Spec}k[x,(x - \alpha)^{-1}]\cong\operatorname{Spec}k[(x - \alpha)^{\pm1}],$ so that you get injections $k[x] = k[x - \alpha]\to k[(x - \alpha)^{\pm 1}]\to\mathcal{O}_X(U).$ In the same way, $\mathcal{O}_X(X)\to\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ will not be an isomorphism for a proper affine open subset $U.$

Comment: @Stahl I understand that. My apologies if I was unclear, my question is "is there *any* affine open subset $U$ such that $\mathcal{O}_X(U)=\mathcal{O}_X(X)$?" as opposed to "is there a *proper* affine open subset $U$ such that $\mathcal{O}_X(U)=\mathcal{O}_X(X)$?" in which case the answer for the former is trivially "yes" for $X = \mathbb A^1$ since $X$ is itself affine. Indeed, the question is really only interesting for non-affine schemes. Thank you for the comment regardless.

Comment: @Nico Ah, for some reason I was thinking that you were looking for an affine example with no nontrivial affine open satisfying the property. Well, you can trivially create non-proper examples by taking any scheme $X$ satisfying the property and considering $X\times Y,$ where $Y$ is not proper. I expect this is not the sort of example you were looking for, however.