# Proper geometrically integral scheme $X$ over $k$ has $k$ as subfield $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, field-theory, schemes

I think this is a silly question, but suppose that $X$ is a proper geometrically integral scheme over a (not necessarily algebraically closed) field $k$, is it true that $k$ is a subfield of $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ for all $U$?

I think the answer is yes, in particular since $X$ proper, it is of finite type, separated, and universally closed over $k$, and so geometrically integral implies that $X$ is actually a proper variety over $k$. It follows that $H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\cong \mathcal{O}_X(X)\cong k$. I claim the restriction maps $\theta^X_U:k\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ are injective. It suffices to suppose that $U$ is affine, so let $U=\operatorname{Spec}A$; since $X$ is of finite type over $k$, we have that $A\cong k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I$, so the restriction map is given by $k\mapsto [k]\in k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, which has to be injective as if  $[k]=0$ it implies that $k\in I$ so $I=A$, and $\mathcal{O}_X(U)=\{0\}$ which can only be true if $U$ is empty.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is fine, but the conclusion holds with zero hypotheses. For *any* locally ringed space $f:X\to \operatorname{Spec} k$ and any nonempty open $U\subset X$, we have ring maps $k\to \mathcal{O}_X(X)\to\mathcal{O}_X(U)\to\mathcal{O}_{X,u}$, where the first map is global sections of $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} k} \to f_*\mathcal{O}_X$, the second map is the restriction map, and the third map is the restriction map to the stalk at some $u\in U$. Since $k$ has no nonzero proper ideals and $\mathcal{O}_{X,u}$ is a local ring with $1\neq 0$, we have that the composite map $k\to\mathcal{O}_{X,u}$ is injective, so the map $k\to\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is injective too.

Comment: Lovely thank you. I think I was more concerned with the restriction map from global sections being an injection, but this is also nice to know.

Comment: For any integral scheme, all restriction maps are injections - the composite map $\mathcal{O}_X(U)\to\mathcal{O}_X(V)\to\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}$ is an injection for $\eta$ the generic point. This has been covered on MSE before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072524/restriction-maps-in-an-integral-scheme-are-injective/1072557#1072557) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2742112/restriction-maps-in-an-integral-scheme-are-injective-ayman-houriehs-proof), for instance.

Comment: Does Geometrically integral imply integral though?

Comment: Trivially. ${}{}{}{}$